# Axios Header's Content-Type not set for safari

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

i'm facing the problem in safari ( on chrome no error ) when i don't send any content-type in header it use content-type: application/json by it's own but safari show me this error

[Error] Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

I try to set the

'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'

now it's not working on chrome. this is my code

```
Axios.post(configs.url + 'api/get_favorite_college',
{
"id" : this.user_id
}
,{
 headers: {
 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
 },
 }).then(resp=>{
```

i want to set the header content-type that works on all browsers.

Comment: Added `Content-Type` to your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy are you talking about the **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** on server side? or in **fornt-end** mean **vue.js**

Comment: The client does not dictate which headers a server will accept. Server side only.

Comment: but when i do  **'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'** the request is not coming to server.