# Axios not respecting Content-Type header

Tags: javascript, axios

This is my axios configuration:

```
import axios from "axios"

const axiosApi = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL
})

const requestInterceptor = config => {
  config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
  config.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
  config.headers['X-Client'] = 'React';
  return config;
}

axiosApi.interceptors.request.use(requestInterceptor);

const get = async (url) => {
  return await
    axiosApi.get(url, {
      crossDomain: true
    }).then(response => {
      return response?.data;
    })
}

const post = async (url, data) => {
  return await axiosApi
    .post(url, Array.isArray(data) ? [...data] : { ...data })
    .then(response => response?.data)
}

const form = async (url, data) => {
  return await axiosApi
    .post(url, data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    })
    .then(response => response?.data)
}
```

As you can see, for `post` and `get` utility methods I use a request interceptor that sets the default values. Thus I use `Content-Type: application/json` for them.

However, for `form` I overrode the `Content-Type` header to be a form.

I read some other questions, including:

[Axios not passing Content-Type header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54565015/axios-not-passing-content-type-header)

[Axios Header's Content-Type not set for safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56947264/axios-headers-content-type-not-set-for-safari)

But my server allows `Content-Type` to be sent in CORS requests:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,content-type,x-client
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

But when I use `form` method, I see that the `Content-Type` is not set to `application/json`, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Why mess with how Axios handles content-type headers by default?

Comment: Mess? It's all from its docs. We use interceptors and they are from docs.

Comment: You don't need the optional chaining in `response?.data`. If the request resolves, `response` is guaranteed to be an [Axios response](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema) instance

Answer (score 7):

By default Axios has excellent request body handling.

- If it sees a plain JavaScript object or array, it uses `application/json`.
- If you pass in a plain string or an instance of `URLSearchParams`, it uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
- Pass in a `FormData` instance and it will use `multipart/form-data`

So why are there endless questions on Stack Overflow with customised `content-type` headers? I'd even go so far as to argue that unless your APIs are using proper [content negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation), you don't need to mess with the `Accept` header either.

I see no need for an interceptor in your case. Simply set the request header defaults on your instance

```js
axiosApi.defaults.headers.common["X-Client"] = "React";
// and if your API actually uses content negotiation...
// axiosApi.defaults.headers.common.Accept = "application/json";
```

As for your *url-encoded* request, Axios 0.x supports this via `URLSearchParams` or a plain string. It will not automatically convert a plain object into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If your `data` is a flat object, you can use the following

```js
const form = async (url, data) => {
  const encodedData = new URLSearchParams(data);
  return (await axiosApi.post(url, encodedData)).data;
};
```

If it's more complex, I would recommend using a library like [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs).

Otherwise, wait for Axios 1.0 where you can [*apparently*](https://github.com/axios/axios#-automatic-serialization-to-urlsearchparams) use this

```js
axios.post(url, data, {
  headers: { "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling for uploading media to the server.
As my global Axios instance has Content-Type 'application/json' and then when the request was made I was updating the Content-Type to 'multipart/form-data' using below script.

```
// Not Working
this.axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = contentType;
```

which was still not updated as the request header in the network tab still contains 'application/json' from global configurations (This could be the possible reason - the global header is saved in some other reference and we are updating it in some other reference)

**So the fix is to intercept the request just before it flies and then modify the header as shown below**

```
// Working
this.axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    config.headers['Content-Type'] = contentType;
    return config;
});
```

With Axios 1.X.X - Updating headers via 3rd argument is also working

```
this.axiosInstance.post(url, payload, {
  headers: { "Content-Type": contentType }
});
```

Hope this will help you or somebody else. Thanks!

Happy Coding :-)