# Nested Fetch with Async

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api

I am trying to figure out what change I need to make to my flow where I am triggering a post call and on success return to run another fetch call followed by a 3rd party generated redirect (Stripe). At the moment I am receiving an error message at `const session = await response.json()`
with the message:

> Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream already read

and I'm not sure how to refactor my code to be able to handle this issue. Can anyone point to what is wrong with my current setup and the rules I might be breaking?

```js
const signUp = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (password === passwordConfirmation) {
    axios
      .post(
        "/api/auth/signup/",
        { email, password, passwordConfirmation },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        const data = res.data;
        setUser(data.user);
        // Set the error message
        if (data.message.status === "error") {
          console.log("Error present");
          setMessage(data.message);
        }
        return data.message.status;
      })
      .then(async (serverMessage) => {
        // On successful sigin, redirect to /api/stripe/checkout-session/
        if (serverMessage !== "error") {
          // Get Stripe.js instance
          const stripe = await stripePromise;

          const response = await fetch("/api/stripe/checkout-session/", {
            method: "POST",
          });
          console.log(`response: ${response.json()}`);
          const session = await response.json();
          console.log(`session: ${session}`);

          // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect them to Checkout.
          const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            sessionId: session.sessionId,
          });
          // router.push('/api/stripe/checkout-session/')
          // router.push('/app/feed/')
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(err.request);
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  } else {
    setMessage({
      status: "error",
      body: "Passwords do not match. Please try again.",
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Why mix Axios and Fetch? Why `withCredentials`? Why redefine the [default headers Axios would send anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73017821/283366)?

Comment: Just don't call `response.json()` twice! Remove the unnecessary `console.log` line, or only do `console.log(`response:', response);`

Comment: @Phil I'm in the middle of porting all of my requests to Axios so pardon my sloppiness with usage of both

Comment: @Phil Really? I just pasted the error message into the StackOverflow search…

Comment: @cphill keep porting and you wouldn't even have this error

Answer (score 1):

Do not call `.json()` twice.

change

```
   console.log(`response: ${response.json()}`);
   const session = await response.json();
```

to

```
   const session = await response.json();
   console.log(`response: ${session}`);
```

Comment: I bet this logs _"response: [object Object]"_

Comment: use ```console.log(`response: ${JSON.stringify(session)}`);``` or ```console.log(`response: `, session);```

Answer (score -1):

you can only read body stream once :) Try this

```
const signUp = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if(password === passwordConfirmation){
    axios.post('/api/auth/signup/', { email, password, passwordConfirmation }, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      withCredentials: true
    }).then((res) => {
      const data = res.data;
      setUser(data.user)
      // Set the error message
      if(data.message.status === 'error'){
        console.log('Error present')
        setMessage(data.message)
      }
      return data.message.status
    }).then(async (serverMessage) => {
      // On successful sigin, redirect to /api/stripe/checkout-session/
      if (serverMessage !== 'error'){
        // Get Stripe.js instance
        const stripe = await stripePromise;

        const response = await fetch('/api/stripe/checkout-session/', { method: 'POST' });
        const responseBody = await response.json()
        console.log(`response: ${responseBody}`);
        const session = responseBody;
        console.log(`session: ${session}`);

        // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect them to Checkout.
        const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
          sessionId: session.sessionId,
        });
        // router.push('/api/stripe/checkout-session/')
        // router.push('/app/feed/')
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      console.log(err.request)
      console.log(err.message)
    })
  } else {
    setMessage({
      'status': 'error',
      'body': 'Passwords do not match. Please try again.'
    })
  }
}
```